# Problem using PyInstaller with a discord bot and cogs

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, discord.py

I have a discord bot that uses COGS(modules) in a folder called 'cogs' inside my main program folder.

I currently use this method to load my cogs:

```
for filename in os.listdir(r'.\cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('py'):
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

When I try to use Pyinstaller, this does not work. How would I get around this without having to get rid of my cogs?

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved the problem but I had to move my cogs out of the folder and next to the main file. Then I added them to the spec file in the datas= section like this:

datas=[( 'cog_name.py', '.' ),( 'other_cog.py', '.' )],

I changed the cog load method to

```
extensions = [
    'cog_name',
    'other_cog_name'
]

for extension in extensions:
    bot.load_extension(extension)
```

Instead of doing hidden imports, I added them to the main file so that pyinstaller could just find them without adding more things to the spec.

Hope this helps someone else if they get stuck.